# Gradle look into wrong maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

when I sync my Android project, I keep seeing the following messages:

```
Gradle: Download https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-base/maven-metadata.xml
Gradle: Download https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml
Gradle: Download https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
```

These libraries should be found in `google()` repo, which is the first one in my settings:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // ...
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
}
```

However, it looks into `maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }` and wastes a lot of time. What's going on here? And is there any way to debug it? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK it should follow order you mentioned . first google , second jcentre and third maven . Are you using latest gradle and build tools version ?

Comment: Yes, `gradle-5.4.1` & `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to [customize dependency resolution behaviour](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior) or [declare repository filters](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec::matching_repositories_to_dependencies).

Declaring a repository filter is as easy as this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds"
            content {
                // Does only include this group
                includeGroup "moat.sdk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is also the option to `exclude` groups and enhance for example the build performance.
Take care that "Matching repositories to dependencies is an incubating feature." The [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/RepositoryContentDescriptor.html) provide more information about filter options.

You can find more information on the specific behaviour you experience below. When it comes to dependency resolution Gradle does inspect repositories in order.

> ### How dependency resolution works
>
> [...]
>
> - Given a required dependency, Gradle attempts to resolve the dependency by searching for the module the dependency points at. Each repository **is inspected in order**. Depending on the type of repository, Gradle looks for metadata files describing the module (.module, .pom or ivy.xml file) or directly for artifact files.
>
> [...]

But as i understand it gradle 'visits' each repository irrespective of whether it has already found the 'correct' artifacts or not.

> - **Once each repository has been inspected for the module**, Gradle will choose the 'best' one to use. This is done using the following criteria:
>
>   - For a dynamic version, a 'higher' concrete version is preferred over a 'lower' version.
>   - Modules declared by a module metadata file (.module, .pom or ivy.xml file) are preferred over modules that have an artifact file only.
>   - Modules from earlier repositories are preferred over modules in later repositories.
>   - When the dependency is declared by a concrete version and a module metadata file is found in a repository, there is no need to continue searching later repositories and the remainder of the process is short-circuited.
>
> [...]

[Introduction to Dependency Management - How dependency resolution works](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution)